# How can I see the Merge HDR result in Lightroom CC?

Tags: lightroom, hdr

I tried using the  HDR option in Lightroom - However I am unable to see the Merge HDR result.

Is there a method to set the HDR merge to be set to appear next to the original (tiff) photo in Lightroom Library.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really a trick to seeing the Merged HDR result. Once you create the image from the popup HDR window, it will be processed and show up in your library next to the original images.  Here is an example, I selected 3 images and the second image was the new HDR image:

[image]

Keep in mind that the resulting HDR image has some unique attributes:

- DNG File Type/Extension
- Filename will have -HDR appended
- 16 bit
- Process Version 2012

It is possible that your library is filtered to exclude one of the above attributes so I would clear out your filters.

Finally, as a user mentioned in the comments I would take a look at your sorting options. It is possible that your images are sorted in such a way that the new HDR result is not displayed near the other images. For example if the input images were created in 2014 and you created the HDR image in 2015 and were sorting by created date.

Comment: When I use the Merge HDR option, the result appears at the _end_ of the grid view, rather than next to the merged photos. Could be the way I have them sorted, I don't know. But might solve OP's problem.

Comment: Good. We agree then.

Comment: What do you mean by Clear out filters?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What do you mean by clear out my filters?  What is be best way to sort to have the HDR photo to rest with the other photos in the library

Answer (score 1):

The HDR merged DNG out of ACR 9 is a 16 bit (floating point number) so it is not a 32 bit but has bigger value range than a 16 bit integer.  I haven't done an experiment to see what the exposure range is between the two different methods.  I know that the DNG one is -10 to +10 for exposure in the one I played with.
I recommend you to use [aurorahdr](http://aurorahdr.com/getstarted/masking-brush-aurora-hdr) for such things
good luck